# JSON only display last element

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a project to retrieve data from json, but the data that comes out is only the last part. Several forums explain that overriding the value. but I still don't understand how to solve it or i was wrong on the array capture

```
JSONArray arrayMaps = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Maps");
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayMaps.length(); i++){

                    Model us = new Model();
                    JSONObject c = arrayMaps.getJSONObject(i);
                    us.setTitle(c.getString("judul_maps"));
                    us.setUrl(c.getString("img_maps"));
                    us.setContent(c.getString("desk_maps"));
                    us.setDownloads(c.getString("donlot_maps"));

                    listMap.add(us);
                }
```

listMap is a Arraylist

and here is my json

```
{ 
  "Maps": [
    {
      
      "judul_maps": "Mario Bross Maps 1x",
      "img_maps": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e8N7oPv_MCs/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "desk_maps": "x1 Super Mario Bros MAPS-1 for Minecraft is a parkour map created by jaxot. About the story, Mario and the Princess are walking peacefully in the park.",
      "donlot_maps": "https://archive.org/download/mariobross_maps/mariobross_maps.zip",
      
      
      "judul_maps": "Mario Bross Maps 2x",
      "img_maps": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iZ5dbVvprkQ/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "desk_maps": "x2 Super Mario Bros MAPS-2 for Minecraft is a parkour map created by jaxot. About the story, Mario and the Princess are walking peacefully in the park.",
      "donlot_maps": "https://matix.li/951a59821a86",
      
      
      "judul_maps": "Mario Bross Maps 3",
      "img_maps": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lbPvLzB8ifc/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "desk_maps": "Super Mario Bros MAPS-3 for Minecraft is a parkour map created by jaxot. About the story, Mario and the Princess are walking peacefully in the park.",
      "donlot_maps": "https://matix.li/bf6ce47f3b2e",
      
      
      "judul_maps": "Mario Bross Maps 4",
      "img_maps": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iKyfNrksGeA/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "desk_maps": "Super Mario Bros MAPS-4 for Minecraft is a parkour map created by jaxot. About the story, Mario and the Princess are walking peacefully in the park.",
      "donlot_maps": "https://matix.li/cf70364bac8a",
      
      
      "judul_maps": "Mario Bross Maps 5",
      "img_maps": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nMIW-BoKdU4/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "desk_maps": "Super Mario Bros MAPS-5 for Minecraft is a parkour map created by jaxot. About the story, Mario and the Princess are walking peacefully in the park.",
      "donlot_maps": "https://matix.li/5cca3c7f677e"
    }
  ]      
}
```

Comment: JSON that you posted is the invalid one.. It contains invalid keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong Json. It's only one Json in the JsonArray. That Json have the same key which will overwrite top message.
You shoud wirte your Json like this.

```json
{ 
  "Maps": [
    {
      
      "judul_maps": "Mario Bross Maps 1x",
      "img_maps": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/e8N7oPv_MCs/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "desk_maps": "x1 Super Mario Bros MAPS-1 for Minecraft is a parkour map created by jaxot. About the story, Mario and the Princess are walking peacefully in the park.",
      "donlot_maps": "https://archive.org/download/mariobross_maps/mariobross_maps.zip"
    },
      
    { 
      "judul_maps": "Mario Bross Maps 2x",
      "img_maps": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iZ5dbVvprkQ/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "desk_maps": "x2 Super Mario Bros MAPS-2 for Minecraft is a parkour map created by jaxot. About the story, Mario and the Princess are walking peacefully in the park.",
      "donlot_maps": "https://matix.li/951a59821a86"
    },
      
    {  
      "judul_maps": "Mario Bross Maps 3",
      "img_maps": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lbPvLzB8ifc/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "desk_maps": "Super Mario Bros MAPS-3 for Minecraft is a parkour map created by jaxot. About the story, Mario and the Princess are walking peacefully in the park.",
      "donlot_maps": "https://matix.li/bf6ce47f3b2e"
    },
      
    {  
      "judul_maps": "Mario Bross Maps 4",
      "img_maps": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iKyfNrksGeA/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "desk_maps": "Super Mario Bros MAPS-4 for Minecraft is a parkour map created by jaxot. About the story, Mario and the Princess are walking peacefully in the park.",
      "donlot_maps": "https://matix.li/cf70364bac8a"
    },
      
    {  
      "judul_maps": "Mario Bross Maps 5",
      "img_maps": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nMIW-BoKdU4/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "desk_maps": "Super Mario Bros MAPS-5 for Minecraft is a parkour map created by jaxot. About the story, Mario and the Princess are walking peacefully in the park.",
      "donlot_maps": "https://matix.li/5cca3c7f677e"
    }
  ]      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Json Object your passing is overriding the values in itself this is array of objects so you should includes objects than fields of the same name with different object
to Create valid Json Object you would try https://jsonformatter.org/ so that you can understand you are using valid object or Not ..

Your Json Object must be like :

```
{
  "myObj" : [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name":"firstEle"
      },
     {
       "id" :2,
       "name":"secondEle"
     }
   ]
}
```

one thing i also want to add here json you are using if it is map it will always going to override the values from the last entries for the same keys Map does not contains duplicate key:value pair